# I need to create a extension for specific page action

Tags: google-chrome, onmouseover, mousehover, hoverintent, mouse-listeners

I am trying to create a chrome extension for specific page actions , the extension job should display a preview of the each href link in that specific page on mouse-over . I know that iframe can be used but i am beginner i have no clue how to do it . In that specific page if the mouse is moved to the href link in the page content the live preview should be be displayed in a frame .
Can anyone kindly help me out in this ?

I have created the Manifest.josn now what are the things i should include in that code for mouseover

```
{
"name": "Hover",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version":2,
"description": "Making your first Google Chrome extension.",
"background_page": "test.html",
"Page_action":   
{
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "welcome"
},
"permissions" : [
"tabs"
],
"icons":{
"48":"icon.png",
"128":"icon_128.png"
}

}

HTML:
<html>
<head>
<script>
function check(tab_id,data,tab)
{
if(tab.url.indexof('https://www.amazon.com/')>-1)
{
Chrome.pageAction.show(tab_id);
}
};
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(check);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

My request is , the extension should work in that specific page and the extension should do the mouseover action of all the link in that page . When ever the mouse move to the any link in that page it should display the link of the page in a pop .

Comment: 1) inline scripts don't work by default so put the code in a separate js file and load it via <script src=file.js></script> or better yet simply specify the list of scripts in manifest.json [as shown in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) 2) JSON and JS are case-sensitive so `Page_action` should be `page_action` and `Chrome` should be `chrome`, 3) A page action API doesn't show anything, it just enables the extension icon on the specified tab, so you need something entirely different - probably a content script with a `mouseover` listener.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm , Can u give me some example of mouseover listener , i never done this before and the complicated part is the hover should work for all the href embedded link in that web page . how is this possible to do ? for exampe check this page -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page . In this wiki page wherever we place the mouse in the blue text it pops up the window . the same i need

Comment: but i cant edit the webpage so i need it to do by extension . Plz help me with sample code